# How do I chain a method call to execute right after a recursive method finishes?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I need some help here, the scenario is the following: I have a recursive method for a Coffeescript class, and it executes itself exactly 4 times. I need to call another method from the same class right after this 4 iterations are completed, Let me illustrate a bit,

```
class Table
  constructor: (factor, zindex) ->
    @factor = factor
    @zindex = zindex
    @dealt = false
    @player = new Player 'player'
    @house = new Player 'house'
    this.setDealing()

  setDealing: ->
    self = this
    $('#deal').click ->
      self.deal $('.one-card:last'), 0 if self.amount > 0 && not self.dealt
      #When the call to self.deal() above is done I need to call checkWinner()
      #How Can I do this?

  deal: (card, times) ->
    $('#player-hand, #house-hand, #ask, #stop').show()
    @dealt = true
    self = this
    if (card.prev() || card.first()) && times < 4
      cardValue = this.getCardValue card
      if @zindex % 2 == 0 then @house.push cardValue else @player.push cardValue
      top = cardPlace + @factor
      right = 550 - (@factor * 1.4)
      card.animate
        'top': "+=#{top}"
        'right': "+=#{right}"
        350, ->
          card = card.prev()
          #Recursive Call is done Here!
          self.deal card, times + 1     
    @factor += 10
    @zindex += 1

  checkWinner: ->
    @player.isWinner()
```

As you can see, the recursive method is quite complex(or not..), and it takes some time to finish given that it does a number of animations(once per iteration). **I have no idea** how to call/chain another method to execute right after this recursive method is finally done.

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Note: I placed one more line of code that was missing card = card.prev() which is needed for recursion to advance. Sorry about the confusion (if there was any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cracked this one myself...

I had to look into JQuery's queue() and dequeue() methods, using them I can **Actually** orchestrate a sequence of events to be triggered, and you coordinate them by using time delays, Neat!

Here's How the result looks like now:

```
enableDealing: ->
    self = this
    $('#deal').bind 'click', ->
      self.disableHitting(); self.disableDealing()
      table = $('#table')

      table.queue "namedQueue", (next) ->
        self.deal $('.one-card:last'), 0
        next()

      table.delay 1900, "namedQueue"

      table.queue "namedQueue", (next) ->
        self.continue()

      table.dequeue('namedQueue')
```

The trick here is the 1900 miliseconds delay. Which is the time it take to finish the dealing.

I hope someone else finds it useful!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should keep track of this function execution ; I mean keep a public variable

```
  var isRunning=false;
```

in the beginning of the function put this :

```
  isRunning=true;
```

and when recursion is done :

```
  isRunning=false;
```

Comment: I think it's kind of tricky to keep track of recursion, especially this one case in which animation is performed for every iteration. Anyway, I wouldn't know for my problem where to put the isRunning variable.

Comment: mmmm in fact yes it is kind of tricky but will work the issue out, here in this case isRunning variable can be set in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right:

Deal is the recursive function.  It calls deal once if a certain condition is met.  Once that condition is no longer met, it should continue down the method chain.  There is another possible interpretation that you need to work with an internal chain, rather than an external one.

Right now, your stack looks like this
Deal -> Deal -> Deal -> Deal

So you can do what you want with two simple changes.  It always helps to think of it without the recursion, and then the answer is easier:

```
if (card.prev() || card.first()) && times < 4
  # <snip>
  #Recursive Call is done Here!
  return self.deal card, times + 1
else
  return self
```

Now you can call

```
$(selector).deal(arguments).show()
```

Comment: I'm analyzing your answer, but before I give you my opinion I must tell you I included a line that was missing. Thanks for you reply Peter!

Comment: I kind of think of a call stack the same way I think of javascript event bubbling-- it has to go up and down.  The thread opens every function, and must return back along the same path.  Of course, there may be another way of doing this (although I don't know what you're doing.) you may be able to have a non-recursive function conditionally called 0-4 times from a loop.  At any rate, another function might be good.  Do you really need to call show four times?

Comment: Actually, using a loop instead of recursion is a fantastic suggestion. I thought about it previously, but didn't want to damage the current 'beauty' that is using recursion. But anyways, that doesn't quite address the problem, which is to chain the method calls, I need something that works like the deferred object for ajax calls (Have you ever used it?), or the jQuery queue(if I only knew how it works) Thank you once more.

Comment: I have not used either directly, but I think deferred is certainly simple and a good place to start.

Comment: Well, I was wrong, and about my own code, what a shame, I just acknowledged that the recursion is necessary in order for the animations to run one at a time. a For loop will cause 4 animations to run at once.

Comment: Just realized-- You can do exactly the same pattern that jquery does.  Leave the chained method to be executed instantly, and just pass in a a callback method as an additional argument to deal, which gets called in the else block.